# Setting a fallback font for non-Arabic charset not supported by a certain Arabic font

Tags: fonts, xetex, characters, arabic

the desired Arabic font is `Droid Arabic Naskh` source [here](http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/droid-arabic-naskh#Droid%20Arabic%20Naskh-Regular). Problem is that when I compile the document using xetex I get funny boxes instead of non-Arabic charset as in the MWE below:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,Ligatures=TeX]{Droid Arabic Naskh}
\begin{document}


هذا نص بالعربية وفيه بعض الرموز الاخرى مثلا (-، * ، + ، )


\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

**Question**
Is there a way to provide a fallback font for Droid Arabic Naskh font to typeset all non-Arabic charsets and what fallback font would be more suitable than any other for this job?

**Update**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,Ligatures=TeX]{Droid Arabic Naskh}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[Latin,Arabic]{ucharclasses}

\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\englishfont}{\endgroup}

\renewenvironment{english}
 {\begin{LTR}\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}}
 {\end{otherlanguage*}\end{LTR}}
\renewrobustcmd{\textenglish}[1]{\LR{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}}

\begin{document}


هذا نص بالعربية وفيه بعض الرموز الاخرى مثلا (-، * ، + ، )

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Marking the language changes with `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`, `\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}...\end{otherlanguage*}` is better and will automatically do what you're looking for, because `\englishfont` would be selected, with the added benefit of correct hyphenation.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still those funny boxes appear when I am writing in Arabic using the desired font. Any idea? Based on that I will minimize the MWE further to highlight this part only.

Comment: If I would mark the text in between the commas in MWE as English language it would be a daunting way to do it. There might be a smarter way of providing a fallback font for those characters not provided by the font of interest.

Answer (score 5):

Marking the language changes with `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`, `\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}...\end{otherlanguage*}` is better and will automatically do what you're looking for, because `\englishfont` would be selected, with the added benefit of correct hyphenation.

For the problematic characters, use `ucharclasses`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,Ligatures=TeX]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[Latin,Arabic]{ucharclasses}

\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\englishfont}{\endgroup}

\renewenvironment{english}
 {\begin{LTR}\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}}
 {\end{otherlanguage*}\end{LTR}}
\renewrobustcmd{\textenglish}[1]{\LR{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}}

\begin{document}


هذا نص بالعربية وفيه بعض الرموز الاخرى مثلا (-، * ، + ، )

\begin{english}This is a text in Arabic with some 
characters like (, +, *, -)\end{english}

ة وفيه بعض الرموز الاخرى مثلا (-، * ، + ،\textenglish{This is a text in Arabic with some
characters like (, +, *, -)}

\end{document}
```

The redefinitions of `english` and `\textenglish` are due to weaknesses in the setup.

[image]

Comment: now boxes disappeared, but the directions right-to-left (RTL) not preserved when LaTeX sees the non-Arabic charset. Parantheses were mirrored in Arabic, for example.

Comment: can I use another Arabic font as a fallback instead of English font with `ucharclasses`, I suggest Amiri font: http://www.amirifont.org/

Comment: @doctorate This is a blurry area; experiment with the various possibilities.

Comment: I will put the code (same of the answer) and output to spot it. Please be patient with me.

Comment: pls see the update. I applied exactly the same code in your answer with replacing the font only and the boxes disappeared but the problem is with punctuations: they don't look correct as your first line of output you showed in your answer. I am clueless to that result.

Comment: @doctorate I'm too: I guess a problem with left-to-right and right-to-left. :(

Comment: of course, I now commented out all what is related to `urucharclasses` using a different Arabic font problem of RTL was solved, which means `urucharclasses` gets in the way of direction somehow. I wonder where to find an alternative to this indispensable package?! or is it still maintained?

Comment: in section 3 of `urucharclasses` there is a description of this very problem, but I am clueless to the suggested solution by combining with `polyglossia`: `by relying on \uccoff and textbackslash uccon to turn off Unicode block transitions inside regions of text`.

Comment: directions solved by using another Arabic font for latin charsets (see my answer) but still breaks by some charsets like french quotes << and >>.

Comment: there is interaction between `ucharclasses` and `csquotes` package.

Answer (score 1):

After some trials and errors, I found one solution to this problem; by using another Arabic font that already supports the Latin charsets which is not supported by the Arabic font of interest. It is just like complementing the required charset of one font with those of another. In my trial, I used [Amiri](http://www.amirifont.org/) font:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,Ligatures=TeX]{Droid Arabic Naskh}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontx[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[Latin,Arabic]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\arabicfontx}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}


هذا نص بالعربية وفيه بعض الرموز الاخرى مثلا (- ، * ، + ، ).

\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

**Caution**
This answers works fine for the small text in the MWE but it broke after couple of pages in my document which is a bit long, in addition one or two charset could not be typset and therefore appeared as funny boxes. So I don't recommend this as a solution to the problem, still answer is only relevant to RTL languages, such as Hebrew and Arabic.