# Parentheses don't appear after the compilation

Tags: fonts, xetex, arabic

I have an Arabic text. When compiling using XeLaTeX and the Noto Naskh Arabic font I can't get the parentheses, instead I got rectangles.

[image]

An extract from the code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Noto Arabic Naskh}

\begin{document}
 وقوله صلَّى الله عليه وسلَّم: «مَنْ أصبَحَ منكُم آمنًا فِي سِرْبِهِ، مُعَافًى فِي جَسَدِهِ، عِندَهُ قوتُ يومِهِ، فكأنَّما حِيزَت لَهُ الدُّنيا» [رواه التِّرمذي (2346)، وصحَّحه ابن حبَّان (671) والألباني في «الصَّحيحة» (2318)].
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you just have 0123456789 and no other text (but the same preamble), do you still have the problem?

Comment: @Teepeemm If I understood you, I should not have this problem if I have text and no numbers between parentheses, this is also doesn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a font encoding problem.  But it would be easier for us to debug if the problem persists even if you have `\begin{document}()\end{document}`.

Comment: @Teepeemm the problem persists even I have `\begin{document}()\end{document}`.

Comment: The code you show uses Amiri while the screenshot for the output shows Noto Arabic Naskh. Noto fonts are split into separate fonts per script, which most of common punctuation present only in the base fonts (Noto Sans, Noto Serif), you your font missed the parenthesis characters and XeTeX doesn’t support font fallback (unlike most modern applications).

Comment: @KhaledHosny I made mistake, so I corrected see the snippet, So should I do to see missed parenthesis?

Comment: You either need to use a different font, or try to do [font fallback](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323575/how-can-i-specify-a-chain-of-fallback-fonts-in-xelatex).

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241191/187698) is a useful link for font fallback as @KhaledHosny answered. It helped with my document.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and resolved it by using the latest Noto Naskh Arabic downloaded from [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Naskh+Arabic?preview.text=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF%20%D9%88%20%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B2%20(%DB%B3%DB%B4%DB%B2%DB%B3)%20%D9%88%20(9898)&preview.text_type=custom);

[image]